# Riemann Zeta identity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

[How can one prove this not using this method?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8K8H.jpg)How would one go about proving $\sum _{n \ge 2} (\zeta(n) - 1)$? When you sum a Riemann $\zeta$ function you get a double sum, with the $-1$ in front of the function, the original sum for Riemann $\zeta$ starts at $n=2$ so that's where the $2$ comes from. But after that I have no idea how to prove the actual sum and the fact that its limit is $1$ and that it therefore converges to $1$. Considering partial sums is what has to be done from the looks of it but I didn't get anywhere with that.

Comment: That identity that you posted is truncated. You've missed a part of it when cropping that image, so your post is completely meaningless. Think about fixing this.

Comment: Since $\zeta$ has a pole at $1$, it should probably be $\sum_{n \geqslant 2} (\zeta(n) - 1)$.

Comment: Yes correct, the sum must start at 2.

Comment: Change the order of summation, and use geometric series.

Comment: How would one prove it without changing the order? Swapping the order of sum doesn't always mean you will get the same answer

Comment: Here all terms are positive, so you can rearrange as you like, you always get the same result (whether that's $+\infty$ or a real number).

Comment: @MatthewAshikhin: That text seems very interesting. What book is it taken from?

Comment: Not a book. It's on Wolfram as one of the identities for Reimann Zeta (115 I think). This was set as additional unmarked homework for my course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Euler-Maclaurin formula gives $$\zeta(n)-1=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac 1{k^n}=\mathcal O\left(\frac{2^{-n}}{n-1}\right)$$
So the series converges absolutely. In fact we have
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty(\zeta(n)-1)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac 1{k^n}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac 1{k^n}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac 1{k(k-1)}=1$$

Comment: Sure, but how do you prove this without swapping the sums or using the Euler Maclaurin formula? Using the definition of a limit and etc.

Comment: @MatthewAshikhin Proving "by definition" is possible but senseless in this question. They just turn out to be based on essentially the same idea, with some epsilon and some delta to obscure it.

Comment: @MatthewAshikhin what do you mean ? using $k^{-n} <\int_{k-1}^k x^{-n}dx$ show that $\zeta(n)-1 <2^{-n}+ \int_{2}^\infty x^{-n}dx =2^{-n}+\frac{x^{1-n}}{1-n}|_2^\infty = 2^{-n}+ \frac{2^{1-n}}{n-1}$ so that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\zeta(n)-1)= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \sum_{k=2}^\infty k^{-n}$ converges, but this is a series of positive terms, so we can change the order of summation, and using the geometric series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty k^{-n} = \frac{k^{-2}}{1-k^{-1}} = \frac{1}{k (k-1)} = \frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}$ get the result

Answer (score 3):

Due to the integral representation
$$ \zeta(n) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}}{e^x-1}\,dx \tag{1}$$
we have
$$ \zeta(n)-1 = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\left(\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{e^x}\right)\,dx \tag{2}$$
so
$$\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\zeta(n)-1\right) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}(e^x-1)\left(\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{e^x}\right)\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x}\,dx = \color{red}{\large 1}.\tag{3}$$
The exchange of $\sum_{n\geq 2}$ and $\int_{0}^{+\infty}$ is allowed by the dominated convergence theorem.